# To recover OSX data in Debian

Tags: osx, backup, data-recovery

I have had taken backups by TimeMachine and now my Macbook Air 2013-mid finally died so I have to rescue files in Debian 8.1. 
However, it seems that no backups of so directories have been taken.

I have backups which have these permissions and owners

```
ls -ls /media/masi/disc2/
drwxrwxr-x       1 root root           481 Jul  5 23:28 .
drwxr-xr-x       1 root root             7 Jul  5 23:41 ..
-rwxrwxrwx       8   99      99     780966 Sep 29  2014 09292014232514.pdf
-r--r--r--     184 root 1922214          0 Jun 24 20:38 100 kuvaa
-rwxrwxrwx       8   99      99  101499390 Aug 17  2014 20140817_Sami_airfoil.zip
-r--r--r-- 1900902 root 1922218          0 Jun 24 20:38 248
-r--r--r--     197 root 1922219          0 Jun 24 20:38 2ndsemester
```

I do

```
su
cp -r /media/masi/disc2/ /home/masi/
```

but get

```
ls -la /home/masi/disc2/
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root      20480 Jul  8 11:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 masi masi       4096 Jul  8 11:36 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     780966 Jul  8 11:36 09292014232514.pdf
-r--r--r--  1 root root          0 Jul  8 11:36 100 kuvaa
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  101499390 Jul  8 11:36 20140817_Sami_airfoil.zip
-r--r--r--  1 root root          0 Jul  8 11:36 248
-r--r--r--  1 root root          0 Jul  8 11:36 2ndsemester
```

but I have to do `chown -R masi:masi /home/masi/disc2/` to be able to read those files:

```
drwxr-xr-x 29 sami sami      20480 Jul  8 11:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 sami sami       4096 Jul  8 11:36 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 sami sami     780966 Jul  8 11:36 09292014232514.pdf
-r--r--r--  1 sami sami          0 Jul  8 11:36 100 kuvaa
-rwxr-xr-x  1 sami sami  101499390 Jul  8 11:36 20140817_Sami_airfoil.zip
-r--r--r--  1 sami sami          0 Jul  8 11:36 248
-r--r--r--  1 sami sami          0 Jul  8 11:36 2ndsemester
```

where you see that some folders such as `248` and `100 kuvaa` are empty.

Are those files/directories indicated by the field five in the first code block really empty?

### dmg2img

It alerts falsely that not dmg image. 
Its conversion of such a file leads to false document. 
Many other threads also about this `dmg2img` tool but none succeeds, etc [here](http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=1072.0).

### tmfs Oct 31 2012 try

I installed `tmfs` by `apt-get install tmfs` which is some filesystem of HFS made for time-machine backups. I run as its manual says

```
# mkdir /mnt/hfs /mnt/tm
# mount /home/masi/Disc2/ /mnt/hfs
mount:  /home/masi/Disc2 is not a block device
```

where I am following the manual

```
mkdir /mnt/hfs /mnt/tm
mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/hfs
tmfs /mnt/hfs /mnt/tm -ouid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),allow_other
```

Why do you get the error `mount:  /home/masi/Disc2 is not a block device`?

This may be filesystem situation. 
My disk is `ext4` in Debian but the OSX backup disc is some default format in OSX. 
How can you recover these files from the OSX filesystem in Debian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of the HFS+ utilities on Debian are, as far as I can tell, from 2006 and lacking a maintainer. Apple released Time Machine in 2007, and when they did they introduced some quite significant changes to HFS+ (particularly to do with hard links to directories). It is highly likely that the HFS+ tools on Debian cannot deal very well with a Time Machine backup.

In your situation I would try to get OSX running in a virtual machine and read the backup from there.